# Part of my object is rendering all black

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been working on an audio visualizer and it is rendering weirdly, even though I have selected RGB, part is rendering black.

[image]

As you can see, clearly the audio visualizer is green.
[image]

Now, however, after I rendered it, some of it stayed green, and some did not.
I have selected RGB in the "output" sub-tab. But it still does not work properly.

Comment: What videos? How are you rendering? "*I've tried everything*" What have you tried?

Comment: Upload your .blend.  If you want to ask a question, you should b more detailed.  We can't just tell you the problem with nothing to go on.

Comment: You have to actually ask a question. No question, no answer

Comment: There is not much information on your question... And **Tried everything**  leaves us with no clues as to what your scene looks like, what kind of settings you are using or any way to help you. Please [edit] your question and give us more details...

Comment: The OP is asking why the display looks different to the rendered output. That is because they are looking at "Material" view in the 3D viewport. This only shows the base color and texture of a material not necessarily the mapping etc. Or it might be a lighting issue. It could be solved by making the material EMIT: 1.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is your light.  It is not strong enough to light up the whole model.  what you should do is in the properties panel, select you lamp options and change the type to "Sun".  This will be able to illuminate your whole model.  Just make sure that the sun is pointing and the side of your model that is facing the camera.

[image]